# Ajax request doesn't send a file, but non-ajax does

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

The following code works:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", data_ajax = "false" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="file" name="UploadedFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

If I do `Request.Files.Count` I'll have 1 file in (given that I actually submitted a file in the form, of course), but if I change the `data_ajax` attribute to `true`, I never get a file (count is 0), neither through the `Request.Files.Count`, not through a parameter (where  the list would be null) (ie:)

```
 public ActionResult MyAction(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) {...}
```

Can anyone explain to me why does one actually submit the right form (with a file), but the other excludes the file from the request?

Comment: file cannot be uplaod with out full post back

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Can you explain?

Comment: file upload is not possible using Ajax.BeginForm, just google about it, there are plugins and other ways to do file upload via ajax

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Ah, alright, didn't know that! Thank you very much for the info!

Comment: If you want to upload files using ajax, then you can use `FormData` - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)